# How to make SQL Query Max Column selection Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am already using this below query successfully in one of our hospital Project but issue is that it does not handle Maximum Token Number, i just want to merge another modified sql query with it to require only one result with maximum token number .

and l already know how to get Maximum from a specific column , for example i can try below sql query too

```
 (Select distinct TokenNumber,OLDReceiptID  From OPD_Token where date=(convert(varchar(50), getdate(), 102))   AND TokenNumber in (select * from OPD_Token where ID in (select MAX(ID) from OPD_Token group by TokenNumber))) OPD_Max_Token
```

this sql query runs successfully

```
left join(Select distinct TokenNumber,OLDReceiptID ,patient_vitals_view.rec_mrNo,patient_vitals_view.rec_cons_name From OPD_Token 
    inner join  patient_vitals_view on patient_vitals_view.rec_id = OPD_Token.OLDReceiptID and flag='False'
    where date=(convert(varchar(50), getdate(), 102))) fit on RS.HosRegNo = fit.rec_mrNo and fit.rec_cons_name = (DM.FirstName+' '+DM.LastName)
```

but i must be confused now , thinking how to merge this with above OPD_MAX_Token

lots of subquery errors i get when i execute this.

Comment: format your query then share sample data and expected output

Comment: query with left join works perfectly but i get issue when a patient is given mistakenly  two token of same doctors on the same day because after that i will get two rows containing data for 
a specific single Patient from the above query left join with  my stored procedure queries working already fine .